# localstack/doker: can't get es runing on default port 4571

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, localstack

So I ran `sudo docker-compose up` with the following .yaml file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    ports:
      - "4563-4599:4563-4599"
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - SERVICES=s3,es,s3,ssm
      - DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - DATA_DIR=.localstack
      - AWS_ENDPOINT=http://localstack:4566
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack
    networks:
      - my_localstack_network

networks:
  my_localstack_network:
```

Then I created a ES domain:

```
aws es create-elasticsearch-domain --domain-name MyEsDomain --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566
```

and getting the following output:

```
{
    "DomainStatus": {
        "DomainId": "000000000000/MyEsDomain",
        "DomainName": "MyEsDomain",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:000000000000:domain/MyEsDomain",
        "Created": true,
        "Deleted": false,
        "Endpoint": "MyEsDomain.us-east-1.es.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566",
        "Processing": true,
        "UpgradeProcessing": false,
        "ElasticsearchVersion": "7.10",
        "ElasticsearchClusterConfig": {
            "InstanceType": "m3.medium.elasticsearch",
            "InstanceCount": 1,
            "DedicatedMasterEnabled": true,
            "ZoneAwarenessEnabled": false,
            "DedicatedMasterType": "m3.medium.elasticsearch",
            "DedicatedMasterCount": 1,
            "WarmEnabled": false
        },
...
```

When I try to hit the ES server thru port 4571, I'm getting "empty reply"

```
curl localhost:4571
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I also tried to hit port 4566, and getting back `{"status": "running"}`.

Look like Elasticesearch never start on my machine.

Comment: Localstack just simulates AWS APIs, it doesn't create a real ES cluster on your localhost.

Comment: Looks like docker image localstack/localstack:0.11.1 does create the ES cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localstack version > 0.14.0 removed 4571 port, see https://github.com/localstack/localstack/releases/tag/v0.14.0

Answer (score 0):

Try using localstack/localstack-full image.
Localstack/localstack is the light version that does not include elasticsearch.

Comment: There is no issue with localstack image, if the issue with localstack image then he should have not got a domain response.